# Adding Google Custom Search to AMP site

Tags: amp-html

I have my Google Custom Search Engine (GCSE) code:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '008589157460623253837:mhsjluzrngo';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
```

However my Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) site does not allow me to add JavaScript to it, and I don't see any AMP components that allow for embedding GCSE into an AMP site.

How can I get GCSE on my site without breaking AMP compliance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting that code in a separate page then including that page in your AMP via the `amp-iframe` component. You will also have to abide by the constraints described here: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, this is not supported yet as it is not in the [AMP Components list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components). Try to file a [feature request on their githubpage](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

I added a search feature to my open source website (https://csaba.page/) with `amp-form` following these steps:

1. Create a GCSE (Google Custom Search Engine) at the CSE (Custom Search Engine) Console https://cse.google.com/ as described by https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/creatingcse if you haven't already done so.
2. Remember your `Search engine ID`, it looks something like "013535696182405026577:kmxne16xdtx". You can see it on the Basics tab in the CS Console, or if you are looking at the JavaScript code it's the `cx` variable.
3. Add `<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>` to your `head` section where the other `AMP` includes are.
4. In the `body` add an `amp-form` where you want to position the search input and style the form as you need:

```html
<div>
  <form method="GET" class="search-form" action="https://www.google.com/cse" target="_top">
    <div class="search-form-inner">
      <input name="cx" type="hidden" value="013535696182405026577:kmxne16xdtx" />
      <input name="ie" type="hidden" value="UTF-8" />
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." name="q" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Go" class="search-button">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here are some blog posts as well:

- https://csaba.page/blog/amp-google-custom-search-engine.html
- https://gfw-blog.netlify.app/2018/05/11/cse-amp.html

And an initial commit: https://gitlab.com/MrCsabaToth/mrcsabatoth.gitlab.io/-/commit/96345716d620b916d1c61cb5b51941378ffc5dc6